# How do I compile a Windows.Forms application on Linux for .NET Core?

Tags: c#, linux, winforms

I can compile my application on Linux using mono mcs, but the result is an executable for .NET Framework 4.5. On windows it runs but I cannot use any newer functionality.

I tried to find out how to compile it with .NET SDK 5.0 but on Linux it seems to not include Windows Forms.

Is there a way to compile a forms application on Linux which uses at least .NET Core 2.0?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Windows Forms (and WPF) are both not supported on Linux with .NET Core and probably never will be. Winforms runs on mono, but that is based on .NET Framework, not .NET Core. The reason is mostly because the internal implementation of Windows Forms is actually an abstraction layer over the Windows GDI, and therefore a linux port would need to be a complete rewrite.

.NET 6.0 will bring a new GUI framework called [maui](https://github.com/dotnet/maui), which is intended to bring real cross-platform experience to .NET. This is hopefully the last step to make .NET really cross platform, as it was actually designed 20 years ago. You can already try it out, as prerelease versions of .NET 6.0 are ready for download (go to https://aka.ms/dotnet-download).

Comment: It provides valuable insights, but some issues 1) Mono does not have a complete WPF story, so "They run on mono" is not accurate. 2) "a linux port would need to be a complete rewrite" is true, but the reason was that Microsoft WinForms was not open sourced. 3) MAUI won't come from Microsoft with Linux support, https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/339 but requires the community to create and support that.

Comment: @LexLi Right, that was to simplistic. With "from Microsoft" I meant "supported by Microsoft". The whole open-source implementation of dotnet core is still maintained by Microsoft employees. So also for the now open-source implementation of WinForms, it's Microsoft that gives the final sign-off on whatever changes get merged. And they said that they (at least for now) would not accept any PRs that provide a linux port.

Comment: WinForms is relatively simple, and had few changes over a decade, and there already is (although buggy) Linux WinForms code for .NET Framework. Would it be that difficult for a few talented people to implement WinForms on .NET Core? I had high hopes when I first heard about MAUI, but after seeing how it is just a big clunky complicated mess to run mobile apps on desktop suboptimally, I gave it up. Again, MAUI does not seem like a desktop GUI framework like WinForms/WPF, but more like a mobile GUI framework that happens to be able to run on Windows.

Comment: @DamnVegetables I agree that it would probably be possible to get that to work, however it will be hard to get a broad community without support from MS. I haven't had the chance to look into Maui, but since it looks as it's the only framework that will evolve, I do believe people will see these deficiencies and fix them. Of course, having no official linux support (as of now) is also not helping.

Answer (score 4):

You can develop  WinForms and WPF UI applications using .Net Core. But these UI applications can run only on Windows. Only non-UI applications developed in .net core is truly cross-platform and can run on Windows, Linux and Mac OS.

The MAUI framework is yet to be officially released from Microsoft that allows UI applications to be cross-platform.

[MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/what-is-maui)

Comment: MAUI has no Linux Desktop support :(

Answer (score 3):

If you switch from Windows Forms to UWP you can target the Windows, macOS and Linux platforms (as well as mobile) with a single visual studio solution. You just need to use the Uno platform
https://platform.uno/

Comment: note: UNO is now based on WinUI, not UWP anymore

Answer (score 0):

C# windows forms use .net, but .net only for windows. Use other GUI tools:

Tkinter
Java
C++, C

which are supported on Linux

Comment: The reason why WinForms isn't supported on anything other than Windows isn't because it uses .NET, but because it's just a wrapper over GDI - a Windows-only technology. .NET is not only for Windows - that's quite a ridiculous statement. Linux/macOS support is quite good for modern .NET Core.