# Deploy .NET GUI applications for Raspberry Pi

Tags: .net, raspberry-pi

I'm looking for a GUI app that I can build in Visual Studio and that Raspbian will support natively.

After viewing several tutorials (like [this one](http://comfilewiki.co.kr/en/doku.php?id=comfilepi:running_.net_winforms_applications_with_mono:index)), I was able to successfully run a Windows Forms app on my Raspberry Pi using Mono.  This will be a good fallback for me, but I prefer something Raspbian supports natively.

I've been looking at Microsoft's page [Deploy .NET apps on ARM single-board computers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/iot/deployment).  That page has a link for the step about "deploying app to the local folder" but that page is specific to deploying ASP.NET web apps, and I'm looking for something that won't be run through a web browser.  I'm not seeing the same publishing options for other app types, but I also don't see anything that explicitly says it only works for ASP.NET web apps.

I haven't tried MAUI, but my understanding is that I cannot target Linux with MAUI (at least, not in Visual Studio, if there's an IDE I could use to build a .NET app that targets Linux, I'd be willing to consider it, but I think I would prefer using Mono to downloading another IDE).

I'm running Visual Studio 2017 with .NET version 2.1.526

Answer (score 1):

Windows Forms applications aren't natively supported for Linux, as is mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68328963/how-do-i-compile-a-windows-forms-application-on-linux-for-net-core). If you want to publish an application targeting Linux natively (which you can do using .NET Core), then you need to pick a different framework like MAUI that supports cross-platform development.

Comment: This is assuming you're running Raspbian or some other Linux-based OS. Another option is to install [Windows IoT](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/) on your Raspberry Pi, but I have no experience with Windows IoT and therefore can't say how well it works.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't think I was very clear about what my question was, so I updated it.